# Get the last inserted id codeigniter and display in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello guys I want to get the last inserted id and display it in my view.

Below are my codes,

**Controller:**

```
    $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');
    $this->load->model('CustomersModel');
    $data['query'] = $this->CustomersModel->viewallcustomers(); 
    $data['last_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules(array(
        array(
            'field' => 'c_fname',
            'label' => 'Customer Firstname',
            'rules' => 'required'
            ),
        array(
            'field' => 'c_lname',
            'label' => 'Customer Lastname',
            'rules' => 'required'
            )
    ));

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>');
    if(!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->view('customer_form', $data);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public function viewallcustomers()
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('customers');
    #$this->db->join('customers', 'salesmonitoring.customer_id = customers.customer_id');
    #$this->db->order_by("salesmonitoring.sales_id", "desc"); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

}
```

**View:**

```
         <div class="control-group">
        <?php 
         $form_label_attributes = array('class' => 'control-label');
        echo form_label('Customer ID', 'customer_id', $form_label_attributes); ?>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'customer_id', 'value' => $last_id, 'readonly' => 'true') ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it's just displaying 0. What is wrong with my codes? Help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->db->insert_id();` is used just after the insertion code then it returns last inserted id.

you can use `$this->CustomersModel->db->select_max("id")->get('tableName');` instead  `$this->db->insert_id();`

Comment: Try this line $data['last_id'] =$this->CustomersModel->db->select_max("id")->get('tableName'); instead $data['last_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();

Comment: Yes I put the $data['last_id'] =$this->CustomersModel->db->select_max("id")->get('tableName'); in my controller. My question is how to display that on my view?

Comment: on View you can access the variable "$last_id". Try <?php echo $last_id; ?> on your view.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Severity: Warning

Message: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 646

Comment: OK.  you need to extract result from query.
 $rs = $this->CustomersModel->db->select_max("id")->get('tableName');
$result = $rs->result();
$data['last_id'] = $reslut->id // "id" means field name